# Repository Pattern in Laravel: how to access method in other repository

Tags: laravel, repository-pattern

I am using the Repository Pattern for a Laravel app and I am able to access from the controllers the different repositories;

the problem I am facing is when I want to access a method of another repository from some other repository.

So far the only way I was able to make it run was passing to the repository the other one as a parameter of the method, but it does not look nice:

```
// from controller
return $this->product_repository->get($request->guid, $this->category_repository);
```

This way I can access it at the get method of product repository, without problems, but how can I access the methods of the 'category' repository from the 'product's one directly without having to pass that like above?

Comment: That's not an unreasonable pattern if the repository in use could change. Alternatively you could include CategoryRepository as a constructor property in ProductRepository and let the application container create it.

Comment: Including it in the ProductRepository constructor, sounded to me like including it twice as I am already including it in the ProductsController constructor, as I am using the CategoryRepository. Doesn't it effect somehow performance? I was hoping to find some other, perhaps some more direct way to call CategoryRepository methods.

Comment: Performance and memory change will be negligable. In fact with a singleton pattern it would be the same object anyway.